# Can't populate Blazor component from parent call

Tags: .net, blazor, components

I want to create a "Repository" blazor component and populate this component when a clla a method.
Can you explain why this code is not working ?
when the method Load() is called from a parent component/page

```
<Repository @ref="repo"/>
...
repo.Load();
```

```
<h3>Repository</h3>

@if(Elements==null)
{
    
} else
{
    <span>@Elements.Count elements</span>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var element in Elements)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">@element</li>
        }
    </ul>
}


@code {
    protected List<string>? Elements { get; set; }

    public async Task Load()
    {
        Elements = await  Task<List<string>>.Run(() =>
        {
            List<string> liste = new();
            liste.Add("a1");
            liste.Add("b1");
            liste.Add("c1");        
            return liste;

        });         
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What error do you get? I see few things wrong with it.

Comment: no errors but the ul list is not filled. The same code outside the <Repository/> component works

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `repo.Load()` is not triggering a render, likely because it's outside the component lifecycle. You can place a render request on the queue using `StateHasChanged`. Since your `Load()` method is already an `async Task`, I would recommend adding `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` as the very last line in that method.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I initially thought the same thing, but when I tested it locally I used `await repo.Load();` and it still didn't cause a render.

Comment: You are right. However, I believe `repo.Load()` should be awaited anyway.

Comment: I don't see why `repo.Load()` should be awaited, in particular, unless subsequent code depends on the state of the child.  The problem is that you have to indicate that the component's state has changed, as Lex says.